# qt4 clear() issue : Am I using it right?

Tags: c++, qt4

Hi I am new to qt4 and I'm trying  developing a framwork which includes certain topic(labels) to be  added to the combo box. Adding topics to a combo box was a  success but at ceratin point I need to Refresh the GUI and load the topics to their default state.

The code itself is called when a the following code is executed:

`ui_.refresh_topics_push_button->setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("view-refresh")); connect(ui_.refresh_topics_push_button, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(updateTopicList()));`

Through the function `updateTopicList()` ui_.topic->clear() is called. But on excecution of this code the control jumps to another function and executes it.

Do let me know what other information is needed so that I can convey the situation properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the probelm solved. I included a check in the onTopicChanged()

```
void onTopicchanged(int index)
{
  if(index==-1)
      return;  // until and unless on topic is 
               //changed no computation to be done in this function
  else
  {
      //Change the topic
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you are trying to call a slot of QLabel, not a function.
You will need to set up a connection, where you listen for a signal when the GUI is refreshed, and you connect it to the slot of clear, which will clear the label.

Check out the information page on signals and slots in the Qt documentation, as well as the functions, signals and slots of QLabel.

Comment: The code itself is called when a the following code is executed: `ui_.refresh_topics_push_button->setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("view-refresh"));
 connect(ui_.refresh_topics_push_button, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(updateTopicList()));` and through the function **updateTopicList()**  `ui_.topic->clear()` is called. But on excecution of this code the control jumps to another function  and executes it.

Comment: @ADI - Do you know what the other function being called is?

Comment: yes, the function is supposed to be called only when a topic is changed.

Comment: @ADI - Is the function that is accidentally being called connected as a signal/slot pair at any point?

Comment: yes, it is as follows:                            `connect(ui_.topics_combo_box, SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onTopicChanged(int)));`    But this snippet is called executed later **onTopicChanged()** is the function called accientally. I don't understand first this snippet is executed `ui_.refresh_topics_push_button->setIcon(QIcon::fromTheme("view-refresh")); connect(ui_.refresh_topics_push_button, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(updateTopicList()));`. How are these two related ?